# How to create a Spring API which receives HTTP and internally communicate with another endpoint using TCP/IP?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create an application which follows the next structure:
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geTBe.png)

I saw Spring Integration documentation, but it seems like it doesn't fit for that project structure.
Am I missing something? I can't found useful information about this.
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

TCP/IP is a protocol like the Http. For me, you can use the RestTemplate to communicate between your API and your Backend.

Answer (score 0):

TCP/IP, UDP are in transport layer of OSI network model where as HTTP is in application layer. HTTP also relies on TCP. So when you are using HTTP you are also using TCP.

The question you need to ask yourself is what kind of data you are transferring. TCP is a stream of packets.

If it is a single long text then do it with a single connection.
Or is the data in chunks? Then you will need to create multiple connections.

Looking at the image you shared, you can send plain text on HTTP as well. See [Mime Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types).

Comment: Perfect! But, should I use something like RestTemplate to interchange data using TCP/IP? I'm worried about generating the socket, and how much time this connection will be alive.

Comment: Since you are using Spring the first choice would be to go with `RestTemplate` and I would also recommend that. `RestTemplate` uses a connection factory eg. `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`. You can use something else as well. Here you can configure the connection properties. By default `RestTemplate` creates a new connection for each request i.e. connections are not reused.